# Selecting multiple ints in query from a varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Consider the following table:

```
DECLARE @tmp_Example 
TABLE (
    TestInt int,
    TestName varchar(max)
  );

INSERT INTO @tmp_Example (TestInt, TestName)
VALUES (22,'Bob'),
(23,'James'),
(24,'Joe');

SELECT * from @tmp_Example
WHERE TestInt = 23;
```

I am getting into situations where somebody might want to select multiple results for TestInt, and I am receiving it like so:

```
('23,24')
```

Without changing the schema of the table, how can I support such a query? I fiddled with splitting it like so:

```
DECLARE @testEx as varchar(max) = '23,24';

SELECT * from @tmp_Example
WHERE TestInt = CAST(dbo.Split(@testEx,',') AS int);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `dbo.Split` is what I think it is, a table-valued function that will return integers 23 and 24 in their own rows:

```
SELECT t.TestInt, t.TestName
FROM @tmp_Example AS t
INNER JOIN dbo.Split(@testEx, ',') AS s
ON t.TestInt = s.OutputColumnName;
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e539/6)

This approach works also (assuming you handle the case where someone has spaces in their list, e.g. `23, 24`):

```
SELECT TestInt, TestName
FROM @tmp_Example
WHERE ','+REPLACE(@testEx, ' ', '')+',' 
  LIKE '%,'+cast(TestInt as varchar(255))+',%';
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e539/15)